# Tablayout height issue in landscape when inside AppBarLayout

Tags: android-tablayout, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

My intention is to have the tabLayout inside an appBarLayout with a CollapsingToolbarLayout above. My problem is when i rotate the phone the tablayout height changes and i can't figure out why.

PS: i'am not handling by miself the orientation changes in this particular activity.

I'am using the last libraries:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop_wrapper"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/backdrop_image_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>


                    <com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel
                        android:id="@+id/backdrop_progressBar"
                        style="@style/MaterialProgressBar"/>
                </FrameLayout>


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:title=""
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarText"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_wines"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel
        android:id="@+id/loading_progressbar"
        style="@style/MaterialProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/accent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Expected height:**
[image: Expected height]

**Wrong height:**
[image: Wrong height]

Comment: This is intended behavior, toolbar height and appbar height will adjust (smaller) in landscape.